# .NET Window Service won't start when Signed with PFX file Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-service, digital-signatures

I've successfully installed my Windows Service on a Server 2012 environment.

It starts and works without issue when the Service executable is not signed. When I apply a PFX signing to the Service, it won't start. It times out over the allotted 30 seconds.

The thing is other environments (both server 2008 and 2012) it works without issue so I have that as a baseline.

What could possibly be causing this? Are there any server specific settings that might be having a security issue with the signing? I do not have control of this box or know of how it was setup.

Comment: Windows may be trying to contact the CA server. Does the Windows server have internet connectivity?

Comment: Interesting... Corret the server has no internet connection... is there anything that can be done?

Comment: there may be, probably some server configuration required. Unfortunately I do not know the details. Perhaps you can check with Microsoft support forums or contact Microsoft..

Comment: Mike, as an update I tested this theory out. Locally on a server where the service runs I shutoff outside internet connection. I was still able to get the service to start. Any more thoughts?

Comment: The service does not connect to internet all the time. It connects once in a while to do CRL checking. I am proposing a possible answer as below.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have deduced by now, Windows needs to connect to internet to verify that the signing cert is valid. Since your server has no internet connectivity, it timeouts.

A solution for Windows XP is suggested at http://rusanu.com/2009/07/24/fix-slow-application-startup-due-to-code-sign-validation/

For Windows Vista and higher, you may have to refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee619754.aspx

In both cases, you have to edit some registry settings.
Do test out; and mark this as Answered if it works for the benefit of others.